# Getbars for matured interest rate products

Tags: programming, bloomberg

Using the getbars function from rblpapi package. Can you extract intraday data for a matured interest rate product?
For example a German bubill

The function works for interest rate products that are currently trading. I.e not matured yet

Comment: Apologies, Historical intraday data. For example if you wanted to build some historical intraday yield curves.

Comment: There are limitations on how much historical intraday data is available on Bloomberg. I believe they have the last 90 or 100 days. For intraday data older than this you will need a different data source. For a bubill that has matured recently you can still retrieve some intraday data in Bloomberg, the older ones are gone.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I appreciate the fast response. I will mess around with my script and see if I can get data for recently matured products then.